# Using twiny() in an inset plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to add a second x-axis to my inset plot that I created with `InsetPosition` from `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator` (following e.g. https://scipython.com/blog/inset-plots-in-matplotlib/), but the second x-axis doesn't seem to show up and I can't figure out why.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()

from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import InsetPosition
zoom_ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
zoom_ax.set_axes_locator(InsetPosition(ax, [0.6, 0.6, 0.3, 0.3]))

def expansion(z):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + z)

def redshift(a):
    return 1.0 / a - 1.0

def tick_function(a):
    return ["%.1f" % z for z in redshift(a)]

z_ticks = np.array([0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 100.0])
a_ticks = expansion(z_ticks)

twin_ax = zoom_ax.twiny()
twin_ax.set_xticks(a_ticks)
twin_ax.set_xticklabels(tick_function(a_ticks))
twin_ax.set_xlim(zoom_ax.get_xlim())

xmin, xmax = 0.0, 1.0
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax)
zoom_ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
zoom_ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)

plt.show()
```

This produces the following plot - without any `twiny()` axis:

[image: result of the above code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `twiny()` has problems with the `axes_locator` used by `zoom_ax` (don't know if that is a bug or not). If you repeat the `set_axes_locator()` command for `twin_ax`, the resulting plot looks like what I would expect (I left out the axes ticks commands to make my example plot more comprehensible):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()

from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import InsetPosition
zoom_ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
zoom_ax.set_axes_locator(InsetPosition(ax, [0.6, 0.6, 0.3, 0.3]))

def expansion(z):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + z)

def redshift(a):
    return 1.0 / a - 1.0

def tick_function(a):
    return ["%.1f" % z for z in redshift(a)]

z_ticks = np.array([0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 100.0])
a_ticks = expansion(z_ticks)

twin_ax = zoom_ax.twiny()
##twin_ax.set_xticks(a_ticks)
##twin_ax.set_xticklabels(tick_function(a_ticks))
twin_ax.set_xlim(zoom_ax.get_xlim())

xmin, xmax = 0.0, 1.0
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax)
zoom_ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
zoom_ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)

##the extra lines
twin_ax.set_axes_locator(InsetPosition(ax, [0.6, 0.6, 0.3, 0.3]))
x2 = np.linspace(xmin, 2*xmax)
twin_ax.plot(x2,np.cos(x2),'r')
twin_ax.set_xlim(xmin, 2*xmax)

plt.show()
```

This produces the following plot:

[image: result of the above code]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to use the usual [`mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.inset_axes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.inset_axes.html?highlight=inset_axes#mpl-toolkits-axes-grid1-inset-locator-inset-axes), which works fine even with twinning.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()

from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes
zoom_ax = inset_axes(ax, "100%", "100%", bbox_to_anchor=[0.6, 0.6, 0.3, 0.3], 
                     bbox_transform=ax.transAxes)

def expansion(z):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + z)

def redshift(a):
    return 1.0 / a - 1.0

def tick_function(a):
    return ["%.1f" % z for z in redshift(a)]

z_ticks = np.array([0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 100.0])
a_ticks = expansion(z_ticks)

twin_ax = zoom_ax.twiny()
twin_ax.set_xticks(a_ticks)
twin_ax.set_xticklabels(tick_function(a_ticks))
twin_ax.set_xlim(zoom_ax.get_xlim())

xmin, xmax = 0.0, 1.0
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax)
zoom_ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
zoom_ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)

plt.show()
```

From matplotlib 3.0 on you may simplify this even further, using [`Axes.inset_axes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html?highlight=inset_axes#matplotlib-axes-axes-inset-axes):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()

zoom_ax = ax.inset_axes([0.6, 0.6, 0.3, 0.3])

def expansion(z):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + z)

def redshift(a):
    return 1.0 / a - 1.0

def tick_function(a):
    return ["%.1f" % z for z in redshift(a)]

z_ticks = np.array([0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 100.0])
a_ticks = expansion(z_ticks)

twin_ax = zoom_ax.twiny()
twin_ax.set_xticks(a_ticks)
twin_ax.set_xticklabels(tick_function(a_ticks))
twin_ax.set_xlim(zoom_ax.get_xlim())

xmin, xmax = 0.0, 1.0
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax)
zoom_ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
zoom_ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)

plt.show()
```

The result is the same visually:

[image]

Comment: I originally avoided using `inset_axes`, as I thought the use of the `bbox` was a bit of a workaround - but this definitely solves the problem, thanks!

Comment: Well, I can tell you that `bbox_to_anchor`is definitely meant to be used like this. Many use cases are shown in the [example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/inset_locator_demo.html) I redacted not too long ago.